# why im getting this error when i run anchor init and anchor build :Error: Invalid Base58 string

Tags: anchor

i dunno why im getting this issue when i run anchor build or init , here is the error : Error: Invalid Base58 string

Comment: Can you add more context to your question? what is your setup like? what command did you run ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the name of the project also after anchor init command.

`anchor init <YOUR PROJECT NAME>`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to initiate the Anchor project using:

`anchor init "mysolanaproject"`

But getting this error:
`Error: Invalid Base58 string`

Who can help me with this please?